# Display image instead of value of a variable

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, uiimageview

I'm just getting to know PHP so please bear with me if my question is not clear. I have a user registration page that collects a field called "`zodiac`" which is uploaded to the database. I can easily call the variable `$zodiac` and the value, let's say, "Aries" is displayed on the desired user's page depending on who is logged in. However, instead of the text, I'd like to display a corresponding image file on the page from my local drive. I've tried the "`elseif`" statements but it doesn't seem to be working. Although I do get an image with the statement it doesn't seem to change when I change users:

These are properly being loaded to the desired page:

```
$this->table->add_row("<b>".$username."</b>&ensp;&ensp;Age:".$age."&ensp;&ensp;".$zodiac);

if($zodiac='Aries') {
   echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/Aries.png" width="45" height="35" />';
    }elseif($zodiac='Taurus') {
   echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/Taurus.png" width="45" height="35" />';
    }elseif($zodiac='Gemini') {
   echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/Gemini.png" width="45" height="35" />';
```

The "`elseif`" statement continues to the end.

Hope this makes sense. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please put your code in question for user changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing the assignment operator = with the equality operator ==.

```
// assign 1 to variable a
$a = 1

// compare variable a with 1
$a == 1
```

So to fix your code:

```
if ($zodiac == 'Aries')
{
...
}
```

You'll find more info about the operators and how they work here:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Works well! Appreciate it and wondering if you might help me place the image value of the variable $zodiac. The elseif statement is a bit long and I'm trying to find the simplest way to have it in this table:

$this->table->add_row("<b>".$username."</b>&ensp;&ensp;Age:".$age."&ensp;&ensp;".$zodiac);


if($zodiac=='Aries') {
    echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/Aries.png" width="45" height="35" />';
     }elseif($zodiac=='Taurus') {
    echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/Taurus.png" width="45" height="35" />';

Comment: you can completely get rid of the if, elseif stuff by doing so:
  echo '<img src="../assets/images/zodiac/'. $zodiac .'.png" width="45" height="35" />';

Comment: Done. Appreciate it!